# Why need to use Media controller and media session?

Tags: android-mediaplayer, mediacontroller, android-mediasession

All most media app also need using Media COntroller and media session. I dont understand why need to use them? if i call direct to MediaPlayer, my apps will run, huh? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are needed so that you can control your `MediaPlayer` even without using the UI,Ex : notifications, Media Buttons etc. and to keep everything in sync.

You can read about it here : [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/media-apps-overview)

Answer (score 0):

They are needed to keep everything in sync:
you can't handle all possible media buttons action using, for example, BroadcastReciever, so that's why we use MediaSession, we create a MediaSessionCallback in the service to respond to all action like(play/pause, next or prev ...) from notification, media buttons, .. and also from our UI(using MediaController)

- media buttons: pause/play button in your Bluetooth Headphone for
  example...